# Changing the join order in a custom RDFLib store

Tags: sparql, rdflib

In [a project](https://github.com/cthoyt/curies/pull/41) we override the store triples method to generate virtual triples given a subject/predicate or predicate/object pair. And the logic depends on either the subject or object being bound to a real value to work.

We are receiving federated queries in the form of.

```
SELECT REDUCED * WHERE {
    ?child owl:sameAs ?child_mapped .
}
VALUES (?child) {
    (<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_1>) 
    (<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_2>)
}
```

which gives a grammar like this.

```
(base <http://example/base/>
  (join
    (bgp (triple ?child <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> ?child_mapped))
    (table (vars ?child)
      (row [?child <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_1>])
      (row [?child <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_2>])
    )))
```

As our triples are virtual we need to have the bound variables from the values on the left side on the join to work i.e.

```
(base <http://example/base/>
  (join
    (table (vars ?child)
      (row [?child <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_1>])
      (row [?child <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_2>])
    )
    (bgp (triple ?child <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> ?child_mapped))))
```

This would allow our virtual triples to be instantiated given that when this would run the triples methods would have both an object and a subject passed in.

Where should we inject an 'optimizer' so that would ensure that we always have the `values tables` on the left side of the joins.

We changed the [algebra.py at line 707](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/4aaaa6fa6a57af8a59ecc28fdcdbd1661941b5fa/rdflib/plugins/sparql/algebra.py#L707) to give the desired join order (inverted p1 and p2). But this would not be maintainable solution, nor would changing the `_buildQueryStringForServiceCal` to have an inline VALUES clause instead of at the end.

We should have this as a kind of optimizer step. Should we introduce our own SPARQLProcessor extension where we add this as a step in before [the evaluation](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/4aaaa6fa6a57af8a59ecc28fdcdbd1661941b5fa/rdflib/plugins/sparql/processor.py#L81) or is a different place a better solution?